# How to implement thread efficient retries on async JmsOutboundGateway

Tags: java, spring-integration, api-gateway, spring-messaging

In my case i use JmsOutboundGateway for mq connection - inputChannel is ExecutorChannel.

Currently ServiceActivator don't have any output channel.
Gateway interface method returns CompletableFuture object.

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface SimpleGateway {

@gateway(requestChannel = "mqRequestChannel")
CompletableFuture sendAndReceiveMqMessage(String message);
}

configuration class

@bean
public MessageChannel mqRequestChannel(AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
return new ExecutorChannel(taskExecutor);
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqRequestChannel")
@Bean
public JmsOutboundGateway jmsOutboundGateway(... ) {
    JmsOutboundGateway gateway = new JmsOutboundGateway();
    gateway.setConnectionFactory(mqConnectionFactory);
    gateway.setRequestDestinationName(requestDestination);
    gateway.setReplyDestinationName(responseDestination);
    gateway.setAsync(true);
     ....
     ....
    return gateway;
}
@Autowired
private SimpleGateway simpleGateway;

 CompletableFuture<String> mqResponse = simpleGateway.sendAndReceiveMqMessage("sdsadas");
```

I tried to use recursion but it won't be best solution.

```
    private void callGateway(int retry, int requestNum){

        String dummyOfs = "dsfsdf";

            CompletableFuture<String> response = simpleGateway.sendAndReceiveMqMessage(dummyOfs);

        nCoreResponse.exceptionally(throwable -> { LOG.info("error occured");
        LOG.info("[Error section CURRENT THREAD in gateway class call ]: {} , requestNum = {}, retry = {}", Thread.currentThread(), requestNum, retry );
        if(MAX_RETRY > retry){
            Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
            callGateway(retry + 1, requestNum);
        }

        return null;});

        response.thenAccept((String someString) ->
    {
        LOG.info("[success ]: {} , returned value: {}", Thread.currentThread(), someString);
    });
    };
}
```

I was also thinking of pushing retries to a different thread pool.

But for me is important to set up numer of retries and back off time and also if timeout for request is reached then retries won't be triggered or stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no retry API around `CompletableFuture`. At least as far as I'm aware. According to your `gateway.setAsync(true)` and `ExecutorChannel` upfront there is no connection between your `CompletableFuture` return from a messaging gateway and that reply from a JMS. The `JmsOutboundGateway` will still produce a real result from its call to the `replyChannel` header after completion of the `Future`, and only after that it is wrapped to another `CompletableFuture` for your messaging gateway expectations. An `ExecutorChannel` is also a bit of an overhead since a `CompletableFuture` return type from a messaging gateway method uses a `TaskExecutor` for async request reply. Therefore you do have a lot of thread switching in between request and reply.

It might not be what you would expect, but I can suggest to change your `sendAndReceiveMqMessage()` to return a `Mono`. And already there you can use a `retry()` API. For downstream flow it doesn't matter and it still going to be an `async`. In the end, the successful result of this `Mono` can be converted to the `CompletableFuture` (see `Mono.toFuture()`) if that is what required in the consumer of your API.